# Uncaught (in promise) Error at o (shallowEqual.js:18)

Tags: smooch

I am getting problem in web smooch widget.

Here is complete question posted in git repo.

https://github.com/alavers/smooch-bot-example/issues/40

Comment: @Andrew Lavers can you answer this. our web-interface smooch widget is not working. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The version of Web Messenger you are using was deprecated in Summer 2017 is no longer supported. You'll need to update to a version > 4.0.0 in order to keep using your integration. Installation instructions can be found in the [documentation](https://docs.smooch.io/guide/web-messenger/#installation). See the [v4.0.0 release notes](https://github.com/smooch/smooch-web/releases/tag/4.0.0) for notable changes when switching from the 3.x version series.

Note also that the GitHub repository you linked is not an official Smooch repository and is not actively monitored for support requests.